# Javascript not taking values

Tags: javascript, php

All of codes are found in the same page , the php is loaded first.The php seems fine because all the data loaded correctly.Using php to load all the contents,I have added a button next to all the records in the table,the first 3 buttons are working as expected..but the rest are not working. Can anyone help me please ..

```
//php part
include('ConnectDB.php');
$sql="select * from PhoneDetails";
$Result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
$list="";
  while($resultlist=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
  {  
    $model=$resultlist['Model'];
    $make=$resultlist['Make'];

    $list .= '<tr><td>'.$model.'</td><td>'.$make.'</td><td><button onclick=" check('.$model.','.$make.')">Display value in alert box</button></td></tr>';
  }


//For js part
function check(model,make)
        {
            alert(make+" "+model);
        }

///html part
<table>
         <tr><th>Model</th><th>Make</th></tr>    
         <?php echo $list ?>           
</table>
```

Comment: Define "not working". I suspect because you're generating completely invalid JS because you're doing nothing with the `$model` and `$make` variables; unless they're numbers, they need to be quoted in order to be JS strings. Also, when asking questions like this you need to post the rendered HTML. Although you should have looked at the rendered HTML anyway.

Comment: You seem to be missing `?>` to exit PHP mode before the JS part.

Comment: I would do further processing with the '$model' and '$make', I want the onclick event (which is working only for the first three buttons) to be able to capture the '$model' and '$make' from each row of the table. And the above codes are inside in their respective tags

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your function in `<script></script>` tags and your PHP in `<?php ?>` tags. Right now you have Javascript, HTML and PHP all mashed together.

Comment: It is only part of the code, they are already inside their respective tags